# How to stream local files over http

Tags: .net, http, webserver

The application needs to play a few Active X embedded HTML files located in the local machine folder. I cannot directly play it using IE since it will prompt for a security risk (I cannot enhance the privileges)

I am checking if there is any possibility to play these local html files (with Active X Components) in IE using Http protocol. The end user machines will not have any webserver for hosting these html files.

/Sharath

Comment: What files do you want to "play", are talking of music or video files?

Comment: Define "play the files" and "stream" in this context? If you mean expose the files as-is over HTTP", that's trivial; if you mean "play as in DLNA", that's a **huge** job. Also define what counts as a "any other web server" here? Does a console exe / service that does all the HTTP stuff count as a "web server"? because: if it responds to HTTP, that is ***exactly what it is***.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I have updated the question